# AngularJS: how to force a directive to refresh?

Tags: angularjs

I have an user editor directive which displays UI for editing $scope.User.
When $scope.User is null, the editor is in the 'Create' mode meaning a new user will be created once data is submitted.

Also, the directive will do some layout calculation. The problem is, before the editor is shown, the layout calculation is not correct. For example, under Firefox, when an element is invisible, the height is always 0. In otherwords, when the directive is compiled and linked, the layout of elements is wrong.

My question is how to force the directive to refresh when it becomes visible?

I tried the following ways:

1. Changing $scope.User 
   The directive watches $scope.User. Changing it can give the directive a chance to refresh. But it is not a good idea, it should be null when creating a new User.
2. Adding a new 'visible' var in $scope, and watch it
   The problem is the directive's parent element (and parent's parent) also can become visible and invisible. Is there a way to get the notification?

Any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-if` to your directive's element:

```
<my-directive ng-if="UserCreated"></my-directive>
```

and trigger its addition to the DOM with another event:

```
<button ng-click="UserCreated = !UserCreated">Toggle User</button>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RZdEX6LhrOwHIbScL69d?p=preview)

Here, the link function will be triggered at the point where the `ng-if` expression is true.

I've made some assumptions about what you're trying to do for this answer. If it doesn't match what you're looking for, please update your question with a code sample and, if possible, a simplified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) to better demonstrate what you're going for.